# Is there a way to pass tables to a user defined function in sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I'm connecting with a postgresql database through SQLAlchemy and I want to execute a user defined function with tables as arguments. Essentially I'm trying to convert the following query into sqlalchemy:

`select * from table1 join table2 table2a on table2a.col1=table1.col1 join table2 table2b on table2b.col1=? where my_udf(table1, table2a, table2b);`

my_udf takes three table arguments and returns a boolean true or false.

So far I have

```
table1_alias=aliased(Table1)
table2a_alias=aliased(Table2)
table2b_alias=aliased(Table2)
results=sql_session.query(table1_alias)
.join(table2a_alias, table2a_alias.col1==table1_alias.col1)
.join(table2b_alias, table2b_alias.col1==var)
.filter(func.my_udf(table1_alias,table2a_alias,table2b_alias))
```

Table1 and Table2 are table mappings.
This is giving me the exception sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression element expected, got <AliasedClass at 0x7f8de1aef5d0; Table1>. Is there any argument of AliasedClass I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

```
table1_alias=aliased(Table1,name="t1")
table2a_alias=aliased(Table2,name="t2a")
table2b_alias=aliased(Table2,name="t2b")
results=sql_session.query(table1_alias)
.join(table2a_alias, table2a_alias.col1==table1_alias.col1)
.join(table2b_alias, table2b_alias.col1==var)
.filter(text("my_udf(t1,t2a,t2b)"))
```

You can amend sql directly to the generated query using the text function, and if you name your aliases you can reference them by name in the generated sql. This bypasses type checking altogether.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**